# Overloaded method value toString with alternatives

Tags: java, scala

Java code

```
String method1(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null) {
    return "null";
  } else if (obj instanceof MyClass123[]) {
    return method2(ob)).toString();
  } else if (obj instanceof int[]) {
    return Arrays.toString((int[]) obj);
  } else if // and so for double, float, boolean, long, short...

  } else if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
    return Arrays.deepToString((Object[]) obj);
  } else {
    return obj.toString();
  }
}
```

My attempt to do the same in Scala

```
def method1(obj: Any): String = obj match {
    case null => "null"
    case x: Array[MyClass123] => method2(x).toString
    case x: Array[AnyRef] => Arrays.deepToString(x)
    case x: Array[_] => Arrays.toString(x)
  }
```

The last line causes the error of

```
overloaded method value toString with alternatives:
[error]   (Array[java.lang.Object])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (Array[Double])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (Array[Float])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (Array[Boolean])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (Array[Byte])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (Array[Char])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (Array[Short])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (Array[Int])java.lang.String <and>
[error]   (Array[Long])java.lang.String
[error]  cannot be applied to (Array[_])
[error]     case x: Array[_] => Arrays.toString(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting starts with the fact that [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) has lots of different 'toString' methods and the scala compiler doesn't know which one to pick.

But the real issue is that _ can match any type including `Any` and we don't have a version of `toString` that will work with `Any` - in fact the most general version we have is for `AnyRef` i.e. `Object`, which you already match in the previous case. Although `toString` is defined for many subtypes of `AnyVal` it isn't defined for `Unit`

What you really want to use is the `mkString` method i.e.

```
def method1(obj: Any): String = obj match {
    case null => "null"
    case x: Array[AnyRef] => Arrays.deepToString(x)
    case x: Array[AnyVal] => x.mkString("[",",","]")
    case _ => obj.toString
  }
```

Comment: is this a full equivalent of that Java code? In Java there were deepToString and toString involved for reference and primitive types respectively.

Comment: Not fully recursively like the Java code so I've edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: now there are 2 errors in your code: one -- it's even less exact, second -- it doesn't compile.