# Spark - Rdd String Cleaning/Manipulation

Tags: string, scala, dictionary, apache-spark, rdd

I have a `spark.rdd.RDD[String] MapPartition` which I created with a filter.

```
val myMapPartition = myTextFile.filter(_.split("\t")(2) == "\"red\"")
```

This filter split my textFile lines by a tab delimiter and checked whether the second element of the resulting array equals "red"

`myMapPartition.collect()` returns an `Array` of type `String`. Here is an example:

```
24344 "someString" "red"
23421 "someOtherString" "red"
```

I am trying to perform some edit on the strings. Ultimately, I was looking at some string replacement logic, but I tried to concatenate a string first. So I would be looking for something like this:

```
24344 "someString hello" "red"
23421 "someOtherString hello" "red"
```

I tried to accomplish this using a `map`:

```
val myCleanRdd = myMapPartition.map(_1 => (_1.concat(" hello")))
```

However, I ended up with:

```
24344 "someString" "red" hello
23421 "someOtherString" "red" hello
```

My question is how can I manipulate certain elements of an rdd row? I think the problem is that my rows are considered one `String`. I am not sure how to properly map this to allow me to focus on individual fields.

**DISCLAIMER:** Scala/Spark noob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to map `split` over each element of your original RDD, so you end up with an `RDD[Array[String]]` rather than an `RDD[String]`, e.g.

```
myTextFile.map(_.split("\t")).filter(_(2) == "\"red\"")
```

Currently you are using `split` to filter your input RDD of Strings, but this just creates an output RDD of Strings, throwing away the work you did to `split` them.

Then, if each element of your RDD is an `Array[String]` of a known length, then you can `map` using a pattern match (using the `case` keyword) to extract and modify individual elements, e.g:

```
rdd.map { case Array(x, y, z) => Array(x, y + " hello", z) }
```

(Note that you must use braces `{}` rather than parentheses `()` around your `map` function when using this approach). Similar pattern matching can be done for rows that are Lists, tuples, Vectors etc...

Update: if you wanted to replace one of the elements with a processed version, this is similar pattern, e.g.

```
rdd.map { case Array(x, y, z) => Array(x, y.replace("s","x"), z) }
```

To print out all the elements of an `RDD[Array[String]]` you can do a nested `foreach`, e.g.

```
rdd.foreach(_.foreach(println))
```

Printing out each row as an array is trickier than expected because of overloaded methods (one would normally use `Arrays.toString` but this [seems to cause type problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301617/overloaded-method-value-tostring-with-alternatives) in Scala) but can be done as follows:

```
rdd.foreach(row => println(row.mkString("[",",","]")))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Two things: Could you discuss how to apply this pattern to something like a stringReplace functionality? Also, once I get the original red of `Array[String]`, how can I print this? Right now I just see memory addresses? Thanks!